# Can't load image with path from FromFile in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, imagesource, fromfile

I'm developing an App for Android and UWP. In one screen I need to load an image from the device-filesystem and display it. Strangely it works perfectly on Android, but not on UWP. The Paths seem to be returned correctly by the FilePicker...

My XAML

```xml
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
Source="{Binding NewImage}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Aspect="AspectFit" 
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

The source i use for the image

```cs
private FileImageSource _newImage;
public FileImageSource NewImage
        {
            get { return _newImage; }
            set
            {
                _newImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewImage));
            }
        }
```

The function which is supposed to load the image and set the path.

```cs
private async void OnAddImage()
        {
            string[] types = { ".jpg", ".png" };
            FileData temp = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(types);
            if (temp == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine($"ImagePath: {temp.FilePath}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"ImageName: {temp.FileName}");
            NewEntry.ImagePath = temp.FilePath;
            NewImage = (FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile(temp.FilePath);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used file picker to pick images on UWP, these images may be stored on the external disk. We can only use a path to load files embedded in the project or stored in the local storage on UWP: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/

So adjust your loading event like:

```
string[] types = { ".jpg", ".png" };
FileData temp = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(types);
if (temp == null)
{
    return;
}
Debug.WriteLine($"ImagePath: {temp.FilePath}");
Debug.WriteLine($"ImageName: {temp.FileName}");
//NewEntry.ImagePath = temp.FilePath;
NewImage = (StreamImageSource)ImageSource.FromStream(() => temp.GetStream());

// Property
private StreamImageSource _newImage;
public StreamImageSource NewImage
{
    get { return _newImage; }
    set
    {
        _newImage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewImage));
    }
}
```

This is also adapted on Android.